# Cannot subscribe WebSocket for inverse contract in ByBit unified v3 API

Tags: websocket, bybit

I'm trying to use ByBit derivatives v3 API to subscribe public market data from WebSocket.

I first query instruments of inverse contract BTCUSD through `/derivatives/v3/public/instruments-info`, and I got this:

```json
{
  "symbol": "BTCUSD",
  "contractType": "InversePerpetual",
  "status": "Trading",
  "baseCoin": "BTC",
  "quoteCoin": "USD",
  "launchTime": "0",
  "deliveryTime": "0",
  "deliveryFeeRate": "",
  "priceScale": "2",
  "leverageFilter": {
    "minLeverage": "1",
    "maxLeverage": "100",
    "leverageStep": "0.01"
  },
  "priceFilter": {
    "minPrice": "0.50",
    "maxPrice": "999999.00",
    "tickSize": "0.50"
  },
  "lotSizeFilter": {
    "maxTradingQty": "1000000",
    "minTradingQty": "1",
    "qtyStep": "1"
  }
}
```

Then I follow the [WebSocket Data Document](https://bybit-exchange.github.io/docs/derivativesV3/unified_margin/#t-websocket), using endpoint `wss://stream.bybit.com/contract/usdt/public/v3` to subscribe topic `orderbook.25.BTCUSD`, and I got:

```
{"success":false,"ret_msg":"error:handler not found,topic:orderbook.25.BTCUSD","conn_id":"027f109e-a7fb-4af0-8b69-78bbb293e34b","req_id":"","op":"subscribe"}
```

Topic `orderbook.25.BTCUSDT` works. I know there is `usdt` in the websocket endpoints, but  in the document there is no other choice. I tried `usd/public/v3` `unified/public/v3`, none of them works.

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe to wss://stream.bybit.com/realtime and send this message :
{"op":"subscribe","args":["trade.BTCUSD"]}

see https://bybit-exchange.github.io/docs/futuresV2/inverse/#t-websocket for the documentation